# Is there a way to assign a geographic data point in Tableau to all non-specified areas?

Tags: dictionary, tableau-api

I am currently creating a map as part of a Tableau dashboard.  My geographic data is based off counties (specifically in New York).  The data contains several different counties, but not all counties in New York are included.  In the data, these non-specified counties appear as "Remainder of State". Right now, all specified counties are highlighted in the map, but "Remainder of State" appears as Albany.  Is there a way to assign "Remainder of State" in the map to include all areas of New York (outside of the specified counties)?

Comment: Yes.  Group all 'remainder of state' areas in one single group and let all others ungrouped.  Use this grouped field instead of your geographical view and you'll get the result

Comment: You might also benefit from reading about “custom territories” on the Tableau site